# RegionPlot with different boundaries

Tags: plotting, regions

I would like to plot different regions, some of them with different boundaries.
For instance if I use

```
RegionPlot[{region1, region2}, BoundaryStyle -> {None,Directive[Black,Thick]}]
```

it does not work.

I was not able to find a workaround. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 12):

I first thought this was a bug, but then I recalled the fact that grid dividers can be specified by part. This worked in this case too.

```
RegionPlot[{Disk[], Disk[{1, 0}]}, BoundaryStyle -> {
            1 -> Directive[Orange, Thick], 2 -> Directive[Black, Thick]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, answers exactly my question! Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. You made my day.